# Django: Convert string of numbers to ip address in dynamic listview

Tags: python, django, listview, format

I have a django website containing a page with a listview. The list, created from a  object-list in a for loop `{% for betr in object_list %}` contains a field with ip addresses like `<td>{{ betr.netmask }}</td>`. The data in the object list is provided as a string of numbers like `"123456789111"`.

What is the best way to display this as `123.456.789.111`.

Tried lambda or normal functions imported as utils, but always ran into errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom template tag.

**Ex:**

```
from django import template
import ipaddress  #Python 3

register = template.Library()
def toIp(value):
    return ipaddress.ip_address(value)
```

In template

```
{{ betr.netmask |toIp }}
```

**[More Info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/)**

Comment: Would this not result in an incorrect IP-address in this case? tmoe wants to convert 123456789111 to 123.456.789.111, but the result of ipaddress.ip_address('123456789111') is 190.153.26.119

Comment: @NicoGriffioen. I belive OP is using `1234...` as an example in the que..if not the custom template function can be changed to what ever is required....

Comment: That is true, but he also specifies that he wants to display 123456789111 as 123.456.789.111. You are right if we're talking about converting decimal to IP, but if we are talking about adding dots in that decimal number, then it's not possible.

Comment: Just need to add the dots in between. Already wrote a function to do this, but didn't find a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module which features very simple conversion:

```
    a="123456789111"
    int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, because a number could translate to multiple valid IP-addresses. 
For instance a number like 192168211 could be written as 192.168.2.11 or 192.168.21.1.

My advice is, either store the IP-address as a string, or as the actual decimal number representation. (An IP-address is after all just a 4 byte value. In that case 192.168.2.11 would translate to 3232236043, and 192.168.21.1 to 3232240897)